# How to edit an existing Excel without changing its original format in Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlrd

I want to edit or insert an specific value in a single cell in an existing Excel file from Python. My main problem is that the original Excel contains some select option cells, images and another sheet, which disappear when I save the new file (only with one changed value). I am using the library openpyxl, but I don't know if it is the best for this proposal. I leave you my code here:

```
import openpyxl
wbkName = "path_to_xlsx_file"
wbk = openpyxl.load_workbook(wbkName)
# Sheet1 is what the sheet is called where is the cell that I want to change
sheet = wbk['Sheet1']
# 54, 6 are the row number and col number of the cell I want to change (insert a 5 in this case)
sheet.cell(54,6).value = 5
wbk.save(wbkName)
wbk.close
```